# How to align 3 Views in the center of the screen in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to align three elements (Views) in the center of the screen like the image below:

[image: Example Image]

The goal is to align those 3 boxes in the center of the screen with that "inverted triangle" format, where two boxes stay in the first line, above the third box in the second line, centered both vertically between the title and buttons and horizontally between parent's limits.

This is what I tried:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/v_box_male"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/iv_other"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/v_box_female"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_gender"/>

(...)

<View
    android:id="@+id/v_box_female"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/v_box_male"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/v_box_male" />

(...)

<View
    android:id="@+id/v_box_other"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_box_male"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bt_next" />
```

However, the third box is not getting "packed" to the other two boxes above it.

This is the result at the moment: [image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found the answer. The problem was on the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/iv_other"` of the `v_box_male`. It was referencing the Image View (gender symbol) and not the View (box).

It was also missing the `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"`.

Here's the correct code:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/v_box_male"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/v_box_other"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/v_box_female"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_gender"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/v_box_female"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/v_box_male"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/v_box_male" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/v_box_other"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bt_next"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_box_male" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for male box

```
<View
 android:id="@+id/v_box_male"
 android:layout_width="120dp"
 android:layout_height="120dp"
 android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
 android:background="@drawable/border"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/v_box_female"
 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_gender"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `layout_marginTop` to the `v_box_other`:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/v_box_other"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_box_male"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bt_next" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
       <View android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_weight="1"/>
       <View android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
       <View android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is the sample code because right now not able to have device but I think it might be useful to getting idea.
Above code You can use **LinearLayout** instead of **View** and that layout you can put gender image.

Hope so you can understand if not please comment